# FluentAssertions: How to break through drill-down of Which/And cascades?

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

Is there a way in FluentAssertions to avoid the automatic object graph drilldown for `.And` and `.Which` cascades?
And some point of the drilldown I would like to go back to the root level and check the status code.

Small code example:

```
    Func<Task> action = async () => await this.someContext.someResponseTask;

    action.Should()
        .Throw<SwaggerOpenApiException<IList<ApiValidationError>>>()
        .Which.Result.Should().Contain(x => x.ErrorCode == errorCode)
        .Which.ErrorDetails.Should().Contain(dictionaryWithParsedErrorDetails)

        // NOTE: This does not work (compile) as it operates on "ErrorDetails",
        //       would like to access root level exception again.
        .Which.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
```

Obviously I could wrap `await this.someContext.someResponseTask` into a try/catch and store the exception into a variable but this is not really an elegant way of doing this, especially with FluentAssertions at your fingertips.

Comment: The `Should().Throw` is already wrapping the invoked delegate in a try-catch and returning the exception. You should actually be using `ThrowAsync`

Comment: Take a look here https://fluentassertions.com/exceptions/

Comment: Thanks, this makes totally sense. The actual question still remains though. :)

Comment: I am trying to build a solution but I am not able to figure out the definition of `SwaggerOpenApiException`

Comment: This is custom and generated code. The thing is that `SwaggerOpenApiException` has a property named `Result` and `Result` has a property named `ErrorDetails` so with `.Which` you can only walk deeper into the rabbit hole, but per this mechanism it is not possible to get to upper properties again (here I want to get to the exception level again). What would work is `action.Should().Throw<SwaggerOpenApiException<IList<ApiValidationError>>>().Which.Should().Match<SwaggerOpenApiException<IList<ApiValidationError>>>(e => e.Result.Any(r => r.ErrorCode == errorCode) && ...);` -without yr optimization

Comment: And what is wrong with that example? `Match` looks like a viable solution,

Comment: But this would also have a very bad message without any context when it fails. Thinking about `var someName = action.Should().Throw<SwaggerOpenApiException<IList<ApiValidationError>>>();` and just reuse `someName` twice on different levels. Will try it tomorrow and give feedback.

Comment: Include exception definition and relevant types  so I can play around with it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These were the 3 solutions I found which enable the traversal of separate paths of the object graph when dealing with an `Exception`.

The order represents the information richness of the summary in case of a failing test. So #3 for example where everything is put into one expression does not exactly tell you what failed.

The first item is very accurate.

1.

```
var exceptionAssertion = action.Should().Throw<SwaggerOpenApiException<IList<ApiValidationError>>>();

exceptionAssertion.Which.Result.Should().Contain(x => x.ErrorCode == errorCode);
exceptionAssertion.Which.StatusCode.Should().Be((int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
```

2.

```
// NOTE: This .Where is not LINQ, it's from FluentAssertions!
action.Should().Throw<SwaggerOpenApiException<IList<ApiValidationError>>>()
    .Where(e => e.Result.Any(r => r.ErrorCode == errorCode))
    .Where(e => e.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
```

3.

```
action.Should()
    .Throw<SwaggerOpenApiException<IList<ApiValidationError>>>()
    .Which.Should().Match<SwaggerOpenApiException<IList<ApiValidationError>>>(
        e =>
            e.Result.Any(r => r.ErrorCode == errorCode) &&
            e.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
```